# Prestashop: SQL: List of all customers who have bought a certain combination/all of the combinations of one product

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

Seeking some help here, I have started to learn some uber basics of SQL to help extracting data. I have put together (with some shared knowledge) an sql query that pulls the name and email of everyone who has ordered a certain product.

I need to expand this to show which of the combinations of this product they ordered in an additional column. Could somebody advise?

Here is the code I have so far alongside what I believe to be the SQL Table/Name I needed to be adding:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.`id_customer`
       , CONCAT(c.`firstname`,', ', c.`lastname`) as customer
       , c.`email` 
FROM `ps_customer` c 
LEFT JOIN `ps_orders` o 
    ON (c.`id_customer` = o.`id_customer`) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_detail` od 
    ON o.`id_order` = od.`id_order`
WHERE od.`product_id` = 64
```

SQL Table / Name: ps_product_attribute_combination / id_product_attribute

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is "combinations of product"?

Comment: Hi Gordon,

In prestashop a 'combination' (also called an attribute) is child type (i.e size, colour etc) of a product. Currently I can get csv of all the people that ordered the parent but it doesn't detail it to show the child attribute.

I require the following data:


Customer Name
Customer Email
Id_product_attribute
Where the product is 64

Comment: seems like you just need to join with those two tables, what's the issue?

Comment: No need to join those tables  , the order_detail "product_name" row already contains combination name at the bottom.